# Different shadow based on background color with CSS

Tags: css

I am encountering a Problem when using CSS shadows. 
I have a container that has shadows on the left and the right side.

In that container I have containers with different background-color. The shadow Is weeker if the background color is darker.

What can be done here?

I made an example. As you can see the shadow almost disappears on red and black background...

```css
#container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#middle{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#blackdiv,
#whitediv,
#yellowdiv,
#reddiv{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#blackdiv{
  background-color: black;
}
#yellowdiv{
  background-color: yellow;
}
#reddiv{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="middle">
     <div id="blackdiv">
     </div>
     <div id="whitediv">
     </div>
     <div id="yellowdiv">
     </div>
     <div id="reddiv">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It just looks different!! Zoom the shadow and you'll see.

Comment: i made a picture and checked it with photoshop. you are right. but is there a solution to make it somehow darker for darker areas?

Comment: No, it's in your eyes (everyone's eyes). You could try some border but it should be quite thick..

Comment: Gotta love color perception :) You could try and set the shadows on the colored blocks itself and use different shadows for different classes, e.g. `.red{ ... more shadow ... }`, `.white{ ... some shadow ... }`, but right next to each other this might not look so nice..

Comment: Color perception is crazy. Three of us were looking at it and we all had the same feeling :)

Comment: If the Shadow is important reduce the Opacity of the background, rither use opacity attribute, or specify color using rgba() , with 'a' less than 0.5

Comment: Increase shadow alpha is one of the solution like:  `box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);`